# USB to DVI adapter doesn't work on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I tried to connect a second monitor to my hp PC so I bought a USB to DVI adapter from ebay last week. 
The model is this one 
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/USB-2-0-T...2d737f4&_uhb=1

I am using hp Pavilion 23 core i5
http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/sit...4892.492883150

I tried to follow this post 
http://how-to.cc/get-a-displaylink-v...h-ubuntu-12-04

Whenever I try

> apt-get installxserver-xorg-video-displaylink

I got the message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
xserver-xorg-video-displaylink : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
```

Then I tried to apt-get install both of them

After installing them and reboot. It directly go to terminal mode instead of GUI mode. I tried ctrl+alt+F7 but I cant return to GUI either.
I have to reinstall ubuntu again. I have tried this three times already and still getting the same problem. 
I guess there is a bug?

Is there any other ways to make my usb to dvi adapter work?

Comment: Try with adding dependencies to the main installation list. `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-displaylink xorg-video-abi-11 xserver-xorg-core`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, after install both of them and reboot, I can't get back into GUI.

Comment: Oh so you mean do them in one single line instead of seperate?

Answer (score 0):

Install common Video card Drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

If not resolved ye, reconfigure the drivers:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
```